# Is AES above 256 possible for OpenVPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I would like to harden my OpenVPN settings. The network is a layer 3 vpn. I believe they are already quite good for today's standards and I will post them below. I currently make use of `aes-256-cbc`, but I would like to increase the bits. Is it possible to have higher AES bits than 256?

The client configuration:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote example.zapto.org 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
auth SHA512
tls-version-min 1.2
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

The server configuration:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ./easy-rsa2/keys/ca.crt
cert ./easy-rsa2/keys/server.crt
key ./easy-rsa2/keys/server.key  
dh ./easy-rsa2/keys/dh4096.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ./easy-rsa2/keys/ta.key 0 
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
auth SHA512
tls-version-min 1.2
remote-cert-tls client
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
user openvpn
group openvpn
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to harden my OpenVPN settings. The network is a layer 3 vpn. I believe they are already quite good for today's standards and I will post them below. I currently make use of aes-256-cbc, but I would like to increase the bits. Is it possible to have higher AES bits than 256?

The short answer is that increasing the keysize will not harden it. AES 256 is considered secure. There's no significant known attacks on AES encryption, and even AES-128 is generally considered secure - there's no known attacks that allows *significantly* faster clear text recovery than brute force of AES.

And brute force is nearly impossible. Even with 128 bit keys, and testing a billion keys per second, you're talking trillions of years of computing to breach it.

So don't attempt to harden it by increasing the key size. That is the wrong tree to bark up.

A better approach would be to ensure privacy of key material. Use for instance [Yubikeys](https://www.yubico.com/) to store the private keys of the certificates, to ensure that they **cannot** be copied. Secure the root certificate key with a HSM, or delete it after you have generated the needed number of certificates. Harden the host machine with AppArmour or SELinux, and ensure that it is in a DMZ with clearly defined firewall rules that controls traffic. And so forth.

In short: focusing on key length is a waste of time. XKCD#538 sums it up well:

[image: XKCD#538]

The cryptographic functions are very unlikely to be the weak link in your setup, and far more likely problems are insecure configuration or out-of-date software, or even physical device security.

Answer (score 2):

You can list of Available Ciphers on client and server with:

```
openvpn --show-ciphers
```

On 2018 in original OpenVPN 2.4.4 release you can use AES-**256** max.

Answer (score 2):

The simple is answer is No.

The `256` in `aes-256-cbc` refers to the AES **key-size**.
I am confused about what you mean by the term bit-rate here.
The AES can be implemented with the following key-sizes - 128/196/256 bits as mentioned in the NIST standards [here](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf).
Higher key-sizes correspond to greater security in the above case.

OpenVPN uses [OpenSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) library to provide the Encryption features. The OpenSSL library provides you with many symmetric-key ciphers. Most of them have known vulnerabilities. Out of the safe ones, only [RC5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC5) offers a key length upto 2040 bits. However, it is still recommended to use AES-256. This is because AES has defeated cryptanalysis attempts by thousands of cryptanalysts for more than 15 years.